# How do I show that $6(4^n-1)$ is a multiple of $9$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How do I show that $6(4^n-1)$ is a multiple of $9$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$? I'm not so keen on divisibility tricks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why -1? Why -1?

Comment: It suffices to show that $3$ divides $4^n-1$ for all $n$. Since $4^n$ always has a remainder of $1$ when divided by $3$, this is true.

Comment: The geometric formula is great for problems like this: $x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\cdots +y^{n-1})$. Just pick clever values of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: -1 because you are not thinking about the issue and statement like "I'm not so keen on divisibility tricks" is rather lazy. So actually -2

Comment: Hint $4=3+1$. Then use the binomial theorem. Or, if you are good at modular arithmetic, show that, if $a\equiv b\pmod p$, then $a^n\equiv b^n\pmod p$.

Comment: @JosephG. What is the geometric formula? I mean, where I can I find what your talking about. Google["geometric formula"] returns vagueness...

Comment: @Pinsgrair This and similar problems are quite easy with modular arithmetic. You should learn it, if you have the time.

Comment: I am... Slowly...

Comment: @awllower Oh, that's clever. I'll do that. I mean, the binomial theorem.

Comment: @awllower I accept awllower's comment as an answer.

Comment: Use induction... or modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

OP says that this is accepted as an answer, so I post it, for the sake of convenience.
**Hint**
$$4^n=(1+3)^n=1+\Sigma_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}3^k,$$ so $4^n-1=\Sigma_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}3^k$ is divisible by $3$.
Barring mistakes, and thanks.

Comment: So, let me ask: what in this answer is so unacceptabke and inappropriate to deserve a downvote? Per chance a little explanation? In any case, I think this answer looks fine, else it would not even appear. Hence any suggestions are well-appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You want it to be a multiple of $9$, it suffices to show you can extract a pair of 3's from this. The $6$ has one of the 3's, and $4^n-1$ is 0 mod 3 so you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Try demonstration by induction. Show the case when $n = 1$, then assume that for $n = k$ the theorem is true and then try demonstrate that the result of $n = k + 1$ is multiple of 9.

Answer (score 0):

The following identity is often useful:
$$x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1).$$
Like many identities, it is easy to verify: just expand the right-hand side, and note that almost everything cancels.

If we put $x=4$, then it follows from the above identity that $4-1$ divides $4^n-1$.

**Remark:** For $x\ne 1$, the identity can be rewritten as 
$$1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^{n-1}=\frac{x^n -1}{x-1}.$$ 
This is one version of the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series. Everything is connected to everything else.